# measure that satisfies finite subadditivity but not countable subbaditivity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I try to construct a function $\mu$ from the set of all sets of real numbers into the
nonnegative real numbers such that $A ⊂ B$ implies $\mu(A) ⊂ \mu(B)$ and such that $\mu$
satisfies finite subadditivity but not countable subbaditivity.

I know the example  when $$
\mu(A)=\begin{cases}1& \text{ if } A \text{ infinite}\\
0&\text{ if } A \text{ finite}. 
\end{cases}
$$
for $A \subset \Bbb{N}$. 
Is there anything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be any function. Then $$ \mu(A) : = \sum_{a \in A} f(a)$$
is such an example.

EDIT: So I missed the part of the question that was asking for $\mu$ to satisfy finite subadditivity but *not* satisfy countable subadditivity. As defined, $\mu$ is a measure and thus satisfies countable subadditivity.

Comment: Why is this not countably sub-additive? If $f\equiv 0$ it is. In fact it always is.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah, I did not see that. This is a measure and thus satisfies countable subadditivity.